# WebSite dynamic port (VS2010)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

How do i change VWDPort for WebSite (not web application) in Visual Studio 2010?
I found many articles that says to click the project and in F4 properties window set “Use Dynamic Ports” to false...But problem that i don't see such option in properties window and I think it's because we using WebSite and not WebApplication / WebProject.
Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the properties of the web site project (F4) and change the "use dynamic port" settings and the port. Sorry, i can only post a screen shot in german:

[image]

Comment: Thanks...i found why i didn't see it. In order to see it, the project should be configured to use Default Web Server!

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2012

If you create web site as file system
Right Click on Web Site in Solution Explorer
From Context Menu Choose use " Use Development Web Server"
This will reload website into solution, hit OK
Now select properties of website project
You will see option of "Use Dynamic Port" and "Port Number"
Cheers!!